# Changing height with JCarousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

I modified the flexible example. I changed the height however the images get cut off. I am not sure why this happens. Can anyone help me with this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-us">
<head>
<title>jCarousel Examples</title>
<link href="../style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!--
  jQuery library
-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<!--
  jCarousel library
-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
<!--
  jCarousel skin stylesheet
-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../skins/tango/skin.css" />

<style type="text/css">

/**
 * Overwrite for having a carousel with dynamic width.
 */
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-container-horizontal {
    width: 85%;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-clip-horizontal {
    width: 100%;
    height:300px;

}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        visible: 4
    });
});

</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
  <h1>jCarousel</h1>
  <h2>Riding carousels with jQuery</h2>

  <h3>Flexible carousel</h3>
  <p>
    This example shows a carousel with flexible item width. In this case, always
      4 items are visible (resize the browser window to see what happens).
  </p>

  <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/66/199481236_dc98b5abb3_s.jpg" width="175" height="375" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/75/199481072_b4a0d09597_s.jpg" width="175" height="375" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/57/199481087_33ae73a8de_s.jpg" width="175" height="375" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/77/199481108_4359e6b971_s.jpg" width="175" height="375" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/58/199481143_3c148d9dd3_s.jpg" width="175" height="375" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/72/199481203_ad4cdcf109_s.jpg" width="175" height="375" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/58/199481218_264ce20da0_s.jpg" width="175" height="375" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/69/199481255_fdfe885f87_s.jpg" width="175" height="375" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/60/199480111_87d4cb3e38_s.jpg" width="175" height="375" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/70/229228324_08223b70fa_s.jpg" width="175" height="375" alt="" /></li>
  </ul>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is what happens:

[image]

As you can see, the images get cut off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your LI to the height and width you desire.  You will need this for jcoursel otherwise it will not cycle correctly.

```
#mycarousel li { height: 375px; width: 175px;}
```